# Resuming career

Tags: manual-testing

I was working in manual testing mainly 4-5 years back. Now after kids I want to resume my career. What courses I need to do to upgrade myself. Is 'image consulting" a good option?

Comment: I know several people of 40 and older getting into testing without any prior experience. Since you have five years of it, jumping back into manual testing should be not too difficult.

Comment: Pick an area that you are interested in, then see what courses are available online.  I took four online courses over a six month between jobs, and it helped me get the new job.

Comment: You had testing experience and you're asking about image consulting. What exactly is it that you want to do? What kind of help are you looking to get here on this forum?

Answer (score 1):

"Image Consulting", as I understand it, hasn't got much to do with being an SQA professional, unless of course you're testing a business' website or other software that is related to the business.

Image Consulting is a good option if you're interested in it, but I would hazard a guess that asking about it on SE might not get the sort of responses you're after. Unless of course, you're actually referring to SOE images for servers/desktops etc, in which case the SE SuperUser section might be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would think skills trump anything else. If you prefer, you could brush up on your knowledge or skills in testing especially the glossary. I find it's useful being able to talk about it and not just being able to do testing.

There are taught courses and certifications. You could self-study if you prefer. Also, the interview is important especially how you answer. I guess you could scan the ads on what are the requirements.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the first thing you should do is research and pick the job you wish to have.

After this you should look over the job requirement topics and try to see how much you know and where you can improve + Find some tutorials/guides to look over.

Another thing you could do is too talk with some friends/ex colleagues that are in this field, maybe the same job but more senior and to talk with them and see how the things are done and what you need to know, in this way you will be also up to date with the latest tendencies.

The following step would be to update your CV and or linkedin profile.

The last thing is to apply for the job and to do your best.